# Trying to make a log in; sign up works tho

Tags: php, mysql

School Assignment: I am trying to make a login but the issue is I can't seem to log in; I am able to sign up and everything and it lists the user that has signed up but I am unable to make it login into the user and it doesn't show the name either.

```
    <?php 
    require_once "db-connect.php";
    session_name('Skyline');   
    // The session name must be one word 
    
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['id_users']) && isset($_SESSION['name'])) { 
        $id = $_SESSION['id_users'];
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $password = $_SESSION['password'];
        $logged_in = true;
    } 
    else {
        $logged_in = false;
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Um, maybe try starting over... Here is a helpful website: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

Comment: @SethB Please, do not recommend "tutorials" of any sort for login systems. These do not have any community support, and if there's a vulnerability, there is no reporting procedure.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: @tadman It is a much better system than what he's got now.

Comment: @SethB Marginally. That code is still atrocious.

Comment: @tadman Please explain why it's bad?

Comment: @tadman, the passwords are stored securely,  it uses prepared statements for database interaction, and though it uses only $_SESSION variables, it is pretty safe for MOST websites.   I use a modified version of this type of system on some of my websites.  If your server is setup properly, it is safe (relatively).  I would not use this system for storing things like peoples SSN, but it is a good start.  The OP obviously does not have much experience with PHP, and so I think this is a good "intro" to PHP login systems.

Comment: @SethB The problem with code like this is there's no procedure for bug reporting. Any popular framework has a vulnerability disclosure process, a team that can build and test a fix, and a reporting network to distribute it. This code does not. Login systems are often your first and *only* line of defense in a simple PHP application. You cannot take chances here. There's no reason to use some random tutorial when other solutions already exist and aren't that hard to explain how to use.

Comment: @SethB That this tutorial uses prepared statements is like saying "he's not a certified doctor or anything, but he does wash his hands, so the surgery should be fine!"

Comment: @tadman, you are right that there are other better systems.  I just don't think they want him to create a full PHP app for a school assignment...